# Installing Sails leads to Link.exe error in windows

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, windows-7, npm, sails.js

I'm trying to install Sails.JS 0.11.0 to my Windows 7 laptop (intel cpu) but receive an error when npm tries to build it. *The error is pasted at the end of this message.*

I'm using Node 0.10.38 (required for my use of the OracleDB module, *so I can't upgrade to version 12 yet*). 
My laptop has Visual Studio 2013 Express Desktop which is used to compile.

The Sails npm install completes using `npm -g list sails`, but with errors, so I worry it's not properly installed.

So far, I've reboot my computer, wiped its temp files, and did everything I can think of.  Any suggestions?  I can't find any compatibility info on the Sails site (maybe I need to install an older version of Sails?).

The `link-cvtres.write.[ID].tlog` file referenced below seems to exist in that directory (which is built on the fly)... at least, a version of the file with a "1" in place of the "[ID]" is there.

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Error Message (in the red output):**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(607,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "link.exe" could not be run. C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\Release\obj\validation\validation.tlo
g\link-cvtres.write.[ID].tlog [C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-cl
ient\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]`
```

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this? I am having the same problem on windows10, node 0.12.5.